# Core Plot iOS compiler error with Xcode 11.0- swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot, xcode11

I have an app which uses the CorePlot iOS library.
This app worked well, when it was compiled with Xcode 10.
However, after upgrading to Xcode 11.0 I get the following error message:

Implicit conversion changes signedness: 'CGColorRenderingIntent' (aka 'enum CGColorRenderingIntent') to 'unsigned long'

at line 481 in CPTImage.m.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest code from the `release-2.3` branch. This error was fixed back in June.